# KeystoneJS - Stripe Integration

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, keystonejs

I am trying to setup a stripe checkout page on a KeystoneJS webpage.

The view.on('post'... function doesn't seem to work and I am not able to find the source of the issue:

Here is my code:

public/js/stripe.js

```
// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');                                                                                                   
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {                                                                                                     
    event.preventDefault();                                                                                                                           

stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {                                                                                                  
    if (result.error) {                                                                                                                           
        // Inform the user if there was an error                                                                                                  
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');                                                                                
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;                                                                                          
    } else {                                                                                                                                      
        // Send the token to your server                                                                                                          
        onReceiveToken(result.token);                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                             
    });                                                                                                                                               
});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
var onReceiveToken = function(token, args) {                                                                                                          
    // Submit token to server so it can charge the card                                                                                               
    $.ajax({                                                                                                                                          
        url: '/checkout',                                                                                                                             
        type: 'POST',                                                                                                                                 
        data: {                                                                                                                                       
            action: 'charge',                                                                                                                         
            stripeToken: token.id                                                                                                                     
        },                                                                                                                                            
        success: function(data) {                                                                                                                     
           console.log('Returns the HTML content of checkout.html');                                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                                             
    })                                                                                                                                                
};
```

routes/views/checkout.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');                                                                                                                   
var stripe = require('stripe')("STRIPE_KEY");                                                                                   

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {                                                                                                      

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);                                                                                                       
    var locals = res.locals;                                                                                                                      

    // locals.section is used to set the currently selected                                                                                       
    // item in the header navigation.                                                                                                             
    locals.section = 'checkout';                                                                                                                  

    // Render the view                                                                                                                            
    view.render('checkout');  

console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); <-- Is rendered correctly                                                                                                                    

//Create Subscription                                                                                                                             
view.on('post', { "action":"charge" }, function (next) {                                                                                          
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); <-- Isn't rendered                                                                                                        
    stripe.customers.create({                                                                                                                     
        description: 'Customer for elizabeth.williams@example.com',                                                                               
        source: res.token,                                                                                                                        
    }, function(err, customer) {                                                                                                                  
        // asynchronously called                                                                                                                  

    });                                                                                                                                           

    next()                                                                                                                                        
    });                                                                                                                                               
};
```

I would be grateful for any help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer just after writing the question:

You must render the view last.

```
var keystone = require('keystone');                                                                                                                   
var stripe = require('stripe')("STRIPE_KEY");                                                                                   

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {                                                                                                      

var view = new keystone.View(req, res);                                                                                                       
var locals = res.locals;                                                                                                                      

// locals.section is used to set the currently selected                                                                                       
// item in the header navigation.                                                                                                             
locals.section = 'checkout';                                                                                                                                           

//Create Subscription                                                                                                                             
view.on('post', { "action":"charge" }, function (next) {                                                                                          
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); <-- Isn't rendered                                                                                                        
stripe.customers.create({                                                                                                                     
    description: 'Customer for elizabeth.williams@example.com',                                                                               
    source: res.token,                                                                                                                        
}, function(err, customer) {                                                                                                                  
    // asynchronously called                                                                                                                  

});                                                                                                                                           

next()                                                                                                                                        
}); 
// Render the view                                                                                                                            
view.render('checkout');                                                                                                                                              
};
```